# Firebase Realtime Database rules for specific property

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I use Firebase Realtime Database in my project. JSON structure is:
[image]

```
"records" : {
    "FwdxA8vqUBW79nT9o9447RT4Yqa2" : {
      "-Lzqsastr4Ywnljvsn-b" : {
        "creationDate" : 1.580395032274364E9,
        "filename" : "4822DF69-8170-4BEE-92CC-18D3435A4E52",
        "length" : "00:07",
        "likeCount" : 0,
        "link" : "",
        "playingCount" : 15,
        "recordId" : "-Lzqsastr4Ywnljvsn-b",
        "recordUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com.....,
        "source" : "",
        "title" : "Ftbf",
        "userUid" : "FwdxA8vqUBW79nT9o9447RT4Yqa2"
      },
```

"FwdxA8vqUBW79nT9o9447RT4Yqa2" - it's userUid

"-Lzqsastr4Ywnljvsn-b" - it's recordId

How to set security rules just for `"likeCount"` and `"playingCount"`:

```
".write": "auth != null",
```

and for the whole `"records"` :

```
"$uid" : {
         ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      }
```

Update: I did it)). So, the correct rules for me are:

```
 {
   "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
        
     "records": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
           "$recordId": {
             "playingCount": {
              ".write": "auth != null",
            },
              "likeCount": {
               ".write": "auth != null",
            },
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: " I can't set rule for `likeCount`" Why not? What is keeping you from setting a rule for that property?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did it in wrong way. I updated the question, now it works! Thanks for participating